# read json file with php // rights problems // how to solve

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have this external json file. With a simple cache. 
Local it works fine. But online there is a foreach problem. But this problem wasn't before. I set the rights of the files and folders to 0777. So actually this couldn't be the problem. But if the cache file will be generated that rights are again on 0644.

Below is the Code and here the warning. http://www.bonc.at/gng/events.php

Please give me a hint.

```
$srcUrl = 'http://ginger-gin.redox-labs.com/api/read_db.json';
$cacheFile = "cachefile.json";
$cacheupdatetime = 3600; // 3600 Sekunden = 1 Stunde; Datei nur ein Mal pro Stunde neu holen

// --- Cache ---
$updatecache = false;
if (file_exists($cacheFile)) {
    $timediff = time() - filemtime($cacheFile);
    if ($timediff > $cacheupdatetime) {
        $updatecache = true;
    }
} else {
    $updatecache = true;
}
if ($updatecache) {
    $str = file_get_contents($srcUrl);
    file_put_contents($cacheFile, $str);
}
// --- /Cache ---
// json aus cache holen und in array dekodieren
$jsonStr = file_get_contents($cacheFile);
$dataArray = json_decode($jsonStr, true);

// eigene events Tabelle bauen und keys aus der events-table-definition setzen
$events = array();
foreach ($dataArray['events'] as $value) {
    $events[] = array_combine($dataArray['tables']['events'], $value);
}
// events Array ausgeben
print_r($events);
// oder so für Browser
// print('<pre>' . print_r($events, true) . '</pre>');
// Beispiel HTML
print('<div>');
foreach ($events as $event) {
    print('Location: ' . $event['en_location'] . '<br/>');
    print('Description: ' . $event['en_shortdesc'] . '<br/>');
    print('Start: ' . $event['start'] . '<br/>');
    print('End: ' . $event['end'] . '<br/>');
    print('<hr/>');
}
print('</div>');
```

Comment: Please include the error in your question. And review these links - [mcve] & [ask]

Answer (score 0):

`$updatecache` is not updating to `true` at all.
As `$cacheFile` is always exist. but your comparison for file modification time is returning always false and `$updatecache` is remained `false`. and `foreach` is checking under `no data`

I updated your code more in `//cache` block

```
<?php

$srcUrl = 'http://ginger-gin.redox-labs.com/api/read_db.json';
$cacheFile = "cachefile.json";
$cacheupdatetime = 3600; // 3600 Sekunden = 1 Stunde; Datei nur ein Mal pro Stunde neu holen
// --- Cache ---
$updatecache = false;
$filemtime = @filemtime($cacheFile);  // returns FALSE if file does not exist
if (!$filemtime or ( time() - $filemtime >= $cacheFile)) {
    $updatecache = true;
}
else {
    $updatecache = true;
}

if ($updatecache) {
    $str = file_get_contents($srcUrl);
    file_put_contents($cacheFile, $str);
// --- /Cache ---
// json aus cache holen und in array dekodieren
    $jsonStr = file_get_contents($cacheFile);
    $dataArray = json_decode($jsonStr, true);

// eigene events Tabelle bauen und keys aus der events-table-definition setzen
    $events = array();
    foreach ($dataArray['events'] as $value) {
        $events[] = array_combine($dataArray['tables']['events'], $value);
    }
// events Array ausgeben
    //print_r($events);
// oder so für Browser
// print('<pre>' . print_r($events, true) . '</pre>');
// Beispiel HTML
    print('<div>');
    foreach ($events as $event) {
        print('Location: ' . $event['en_location'] . '<br/>');
        print('Description: ' . $event['en_shortdesc'] . '<br/>');
        print('Start: ' . $event['start'] . '<br/>');
        print('End: ' . $event['end'] . '<br/>');
        print('<hr/>');
    }
}
?>
```

**OUTPUT-**

[image]

Hope this helps you

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted. It will be helpful to other users

Comment: First, thank you Rohan.
Local it works perfectly. But on there is always that problem with the foreach and I couldn't understand this.

I set the rights to 0777.  Which settings are important on the server? Where is the trick. Please help me again. Thanks

Comment: change permission for cachefile.json by  `chmod +777 cachefile.json`

Comment: I deleted the "Cache - Code". Local, it  works perfectly but online there is always a foreach problem. I couldn't unterstand this. May somebody can help me. Online Version: http://www.bonc.at/gng/events.php